# I have this error and i don't understand why: int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

This is my code (a small part of it but you have here all is neccesaire for understanding the error i think).
Also, my code should apply the **DELTA RULE**

```
import numpy as np
import random
y = np.array([[ 45, 85, -1],
              [ 50, 43, -1],
              [ 40, 80, -1],
              [ 55, 42, -1],
              [200, 43, -1],
              [ 48, 40, -1],
              [195, 41, -1],
              [ 43, 87, -1],
              [190, 40, -1]])
w = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(9,3))
```

My w will look like:

```
array([[ 0.56,  0.68,  0.10],
       [-0.62, -0.07, -0.75],
       [-0.89, -0.42, -0.21],
       [-0.20,  0.59,  0.23],
       [-0.06,  0.25, -0.56],
       [-0.71,  0.17,  0.61],
       [ 0.43, -0.11,  0.04],
       [ 0.40, -0.77, -0.66],
       [-0.24, -0.60,  0.62]])
```

the rest of the code is this and this is what my problem has to solve

```
o = np.zeros(shape=(9,3))
net = np.zeros(shape=(9,3))
e = 2.71828182846


for i in range(0,9):
   #print("Pattern(Step) %d"% (i+1))
   for j in range(0,3):

       net[i,j] = np.dot(y[i,j],w[i,j])
       o[i,j] = 2/(1+e**(-net[i,j]))-1
       print("\nnet[%d,%d]:"% (i,j))
```

For me o will be an array which will calculate almost the same thing like

```
np.sign(net[i,j])
```

but the values will be float type instead of integers like in np.sign function

The error is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-2719c5d1251f> in <module>()
      8     #print("Pattern(Step) %d"% (i+1))
      9     for j in range(0,3):
---> 10         net[i,j] = np.dot(y[i,j],w[i,j])
     11         o[i,j] = 2/(1+e**(-net[i,j]))-1
     12         print("\nnet[%d,%d]:"% (i,j))

 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I really do not understand why it gives me an error...

Please help me.

Also,

If i normalize the values from y array and put them in another array and use that array instead of y it will not give me this error anymore.
    But the problem there is that for the minimum elements in the y array the normalized value will be zero and as a result some of my net[i,j] values will be zero and it will mess up my program. because zero will block me from calculating some further values in the programme.

Comment: there are 3 `[]` operations in the line where the error occurs. Try to decompose the line in 3 assignment to see which one is the problem. You may be able to figure it out at that point.

Comment: Lots of things wrong with this code. You are getting this error most likely because you assigned the names y, w, or net to an integer. `np.dot` is not meant to operate in scalars but in arrays (1D or 2D). By using it in a loop it will kill performance. You should use the numpy functions on full arrays, not in loops.

Comment: like using print() on every [] operation to see what i get from each one of them?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It seemn like it has a problem with the y [ ]. if i use print(y[i,j) that is where i get an error...

Comment: @tiago so if i use np.dot(y, w) it should not give me an error anymore?... Sorry for the trouble, but I am still a beginner

Comment: @BiancaTrifanescu: from your code we don't have enough information about what you are trying to do. `np.dot` is the dot product function, but you are using it for a simple multiplication of two numbers (you can use `*` instead...). I don't know if your problem requires a dot product or simple element-wise multiplication. If the latter, you could just do `o = 2 / (1 + np.exp(-(y * w))) - 1`. No need for loops.

Comment: @tiago thank you. i will try that :)